# Xcode: use of undeclared identifier setprecision (C++)

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying to implement C++ code on my project and I'm trying to format float number with 2 decimals. Here is my code:

```
float number = 15.101010101010;
cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Use of undeclared identifier setprecision
```

[image]
Any of you knows why I'm getting this error or how can fixed?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: You probably forgot to include the right header file, or forgot to call it by its name `std::setprecision`, or both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include the `iomanip` header to use [std::setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).